# How do I tell which application is using which port?

Tags: macos, ports

I have been looking at `netstat` output on a MacBook. I noticed that some applications enable you to specify which port it uses. For example, `utorrent` allows you to do that. I chose a port 55743 then ran `netstat | grep 55743` and the output was the following.

```
udp6       0      0  *.55743                *.*
udp4       0      0  *.55743                *.*
```

When I quit `utorrent` the port is released. But, if I did not know the port number then how can I tell what application is using which port? And is it possible for some applications to secretly use ports to communicate with external servers devices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As David Houde mentioned, `lsof -i` is your friend gives you a snapshot of current socket connections/operations. Unfortunately, on OS X, `netstat` does not support this feature.

Other options include:

`Activity Monitor.app` allows you to see the files and ports open by an application. This can be done by double clicking on a process and opening the "Open files and ports" tab.

Dtrace - check out [soconnect](http://dtracebook.com/index.php/Network_Lower_Level_Protocols:soconnect.d#Mac_OS_X) script which gives you continuous information about network operations until you quit (control+c). Example output:

```
sudo /tmp/soconnect.d 
PID    PROCESS          FAM ADDRESS          PORT   LAT(us) RESULT
8211   X-Lite           2   192.168.1.109    5060        25 Success
4112   Google Chrome    2   173.194.34.134   443         53 In progress
8211   X-Lite           2   192.168.1.109    5060        30 Success
```

One application that I quite like personally is little snitch but it happens to be commercial software. Although this is a desktop firewall software, it has a number of features that might be interesting for you:

- network monitor, which tells you which applications are connecting to where (similar to the soconnect.d output in a way)
- capture network traffic per application (i.e. similar to wireshark, you can watch network traffic, but limit it to only a specific application)

To answer your second question - yes, on traditional operating systems (e.g. OS X, Windows), applications have the ability to connect to third party systems in various ways and send anything. A number of desktop firewalls try to address this issue by allowing you to specify where each application can connect to, thus having a sort of whitelist. Like anything else in security, this approach is not without its pitfalls.

ps. I have no association with any desktop firewall software vendors :)

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this with some more netstat arguments, or by using lsof:

```
netstat -lp
lsof -i udp:55743
```